# How can one prevent a Windows Scheduled Task from being killed upon OS sleep?

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I have a Scheduled Task which runs an application upon user logon with the "run with highest privileges" checkbox turned on, so that the application can launch with admin rights. Unfortunately, when my OS enters sleep, the task is killed.

I have checked the "Run only when user is logged on" checkbox. But OS sleep is NOT considered log-off, even though it prompts for password upon return, right?

Even more, I tried to switch to "Run whether the user is logged on or not", including toggling the "Do not store password" checkbox on AND off. Neither of this options started my application :(.

Comment: This is because when the OS goes to sleep it puts the HDD to sleep also which does not allow your Task to run because the Task is on the Hard Drive.

Comment: Any way to re-run the task upon come-back from sleep? Also: how come other programs that are on and have tons of resources upon the Storage media including open files are restored just fine from the sleep state? This makes no sense to me...

Comment: You can check the “Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" and it should run when it wakes up.

Comment: Trying... trying... tried. Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found how to fix this. Add another trigger for running the task. Not only "at logon" but also "on workstation unlock". Combined with the "if the task is already running -> do not start a new instance", everything works fine :). I prefer this solution because it does not require tampering with wake timers :).

Answer (score 1):

from start menu type "power options
in power options' change plan settings click "change plan settings"
click "change advanced power settings"
click the + next to sleep
click the + next to "allow wake timers"
set to enable for plugged in and optionally on battery

Comment: If I enable this on battery, will it keep the computer alive when the computer is on battery? So instead of sleeping the CPU & HDD will remain on? So basically it's impossible to achieve with full sleep state? I wonder how other programs do it just fine.

Comment: A sleeping computer is the same as a plugged in computer, except that the sleep mode is powered by the battery. (so yes, still alive) Of course, if the battery runs down, the computer will harmlessly shut itself off. On a good battery, a sleeping computer will sleep for several days with no problem.

Comment: I will clarify my comment-question :) : you mentioned "allow wake timers". That, to me, smells like keeping the CPU and/or Storage powered. During sleep, these should NOT be powered, as the CPU consumes a lot of power. During sleep, it's only the RAM that is powered. That is why I asked you the question "So basically it's impossible to achieve with full sleep state"? :)

Comment: From a PC Mag website, sleep is defined as: "A low power mode in a computer. Also called "standby mode," the screen and hard disks are turned off, but the memory (RAM) chips are continually refreshed in order to retain their contents. In addition, the CPU is throttled down to its lowest power state." And, yes, the CPU is still on, but at a greatly reduced state. Just enough for it to respond to stimuli, such as keyboard or mouse action, or Task Scheduler command. I suggest that you Google "computer sleep" for more information. The hard drive is also fully shut down during Sleep to save energy.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, I realize now, because indeed the CPU must respond to the mouse/keyboard interrupt. My bad :).